# Why my 2nd level cache implementation runs into error?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to implement second-level cache on my application, but it returns following error. I am suspicious to the setCacheMode.

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
 ...
  <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
  </property>

  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
 ...
```

**Product.Java**

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Cache(usage= CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }
...
}
```

**Model.Java**

```
....
final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try {
            final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            try {
                Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id);
                session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL);
                tx.commit();
                return product;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            HibernateUtil.closeSession();
        }
.....
```

**Error**

```
INFO: ** Exception in SessionFactory **
SEVERE: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
    at com.my.util.HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:26)
    at com.my.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:43)
    at com.my.controller.Default.execute(Default.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at 
    .....
```

**Util**

```
 private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new 
                     ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .buildServiceRegistry();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.append("** Exception in SessionFactory **");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return sessionFactory;
  }
```

Comment: Dont know if this will solve your issue. Add the below property to turn on 2nd level cache.                                       <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>

Comment: @Sanj 've added that but still runs into same error

Answer (score 6):

If you use hibernate version higher than 3.3, you need use this properties

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
   </property>
```

and add dependancy to maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then you use 
Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id); 
this will be second level cache(if session is close), not query.

Comment: Once I used it application ran into this error "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)"

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. (I am using Hibernate 4.2.0.Final).  I also read the instruction of this article: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/hibernate-cache-levels-tutorial.html (which, however, did not mention the need to add `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` -- I guess it is a bit outdated (from 2012))

Answer (score 0):

well your hbm config is missing vital parts for second level cache usage. Please add `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache` and `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` options. DO consult the hbm manual for your version of hibernate for correct class values for factory.

Answer (score -1):

If you use hibernate version higher than 3.3, you need use this property:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
     org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
```

and add a dependency to maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and then you use:

```
Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id);
```

this will be second level cache (if session is closed), not query.

Also you need to override the `buildsessionFactory`.
Check what methods you are using in previous versions of hibernate.
Then check what the higher version is using -- that method only you need to override.

Now I override the `buildsessionfactory` method because I am using hibernate4.3.11-final.